# How do I merge two List of String into one List without duplicate in Java8 stream

Tags: java, collections, java-8, java-stream

Here, I have two lists of items that I want to merge into one list and remove duplicate before saving to the database. But I'm getting an error that " Non-static method cannot be referenced from a static context". Though I know the meaning of that message, I don't know how to solve it in this context of Java8 Stream. Please, help.

```
 public void addItems(String shopId, List<String>itemsToAdd, String adminId) {
    final Shop  shop = shopSrevice.getShopById(shopId);
    final Optional<List<String>> currentItems= shop.getCurrentItems();
    if (currentItems.isPresent()){
        List<String> allItems = Stream.of(currentItems,itemsToAdd)
                .flatMap(Collection::stream)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

[Here is the snapshot of the error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rnq6G.png)

Comment: a typo? you just diidn't call `get` after `isPresent`  as in `List<String> allItems = Stream.of(currentItems.get(),itemsToAdd)
                .flatMap(Collection::stream)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());` and possibly without the check you can simply perform `List<String> allItems = Stream.of(currentItems.orElse(Collections.emptyList()), itemsToAdd)
                .flatMap(Collection::stream)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you're trying to make a stream of an Optional list and a list. Calling `get()` on currentItems solves this error, and shouldn't be a problem as you're already checking whether it is present.

Comment: Yes, bro, calling the get() on the currentItems actually solved the error. thanks.

Comment: It doesn't, it works only if Optional is not empty which is not guaranteed. In case the Optional is empty, an exception is thrown. That’s why I have suggested using Optional.orElse method that provides an empty collection to return when the Optional is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Use `distinct()`

```
Stream.of(currentItems.get(),itemsToAdd)
        .flatMap(List::stream)
        .distinct()
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

`currentItems` is not a `List` but an `Optional`, therefore the subsequent methods make no sence. Unwrap the `Optional` and therefore `currentItems.isPresent()` can be omitted. The method `Stream::distinct` assures unique items (or use `Set` instead):

```
final Shop  shop = shopSrevice.getShopById(shopId);
final Optional<List<String>> currentItems= shop.getCurrentItems();
final List<String> currentItemsList = currentItems.orElse(Collections.emptyList());

List<String> allItems = Stream.of(currentItemsList, itemsToAdd)
     .flatMap(Collection::stream)
     .distinct()
     .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Alright, thank you everyone for your answers, calling the **get()** on the **currentItems** actually solved the error.